# IronSource banner loading shows "empty waterfall"

Tags: ironsource

Using IronSource mediation loading a banner fails with error ***empty waterfall***.
SDK intitialization itself finishes successfully.

```
BannerDelegate didFailToLoadWithError(_:)Optional(Error Domain= Code=606 "Empty waterfall" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Empty waterfall})
```

I load a banner as following:

```
let bannerSize: ISBannerSize = ISBannerSize(description:"ISBannerSize_BANNER", width:320, height:50)
IronSource.loadBanner(with: self, size: bannerSize)
```

I use the string ***ISBannerSize_BANNER*** for a standard banner as it says in the official documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the ISBannerSize parameter.
It should be ***BANNER***, ***LARGE***, ***RECTANGLE***...

```
let bannerSize: ISBannerSize = ISBannerSize(description:"BANNER", width:320, height:50)
```

for ***SMART***

```
let bannerSize: ISBannerSize = ISBannerSize(description:"SMART", width:0, height:0)
```